# Public Desktop icons plus more not showing

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, desktop, desktop-icons

We have one user on one computer that all of the Public Desktop icons is missing from her computer, plus  things like recycle bin. Her personal icons are showing as they should, just not the public and system ones.

I cannot seem to find any one else with the problem on Google. Has anyone ever run into this?

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the common desktop icons are enabled under "Control Panel > Personalization > Change Desktop Settings". If the icons are not selected, then check all the icons to be displayed in the desktop.

[image]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where (Desktop context menu) → View → Show Icons and the check boxes in Desktop Icon Settings didn't seem to matter.

I began to suspect `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop` because my remaining icons went all over the place. I ended up deleting it - after exporting it - and restarting the computer. All of the icons came back in their default locations.

I also deleted `Users\my username\AppData\local\IconCache.db`, though I don't think that it did anything because I had tried it before.

Comment: Randomly deleting registry keys is a great way to make your computer unreliable. Can you link to any documentation suggesting that the changes you make will have the desired effect?